# FancyFileUpload - File Uploader For jQuery and MVC CORE

Tags: jquery, file-upload, fancybox, jquery-file-upload

I'm trying to use the "**FancyFileUpload**" j*query plugin* on my site to upload an image.

This is the link to the plugin used
https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Fancy-File-Uploader-jQuery.html

I would like to know if there is the possibility to link the upload to a single file and if it is possible to start the upload directly when I choose the file.

in the parameters to pass to the plugin there is also

```
// jQuery File Upload options
'fileupload': {singleFileUploads:true}
```

which has a singleFileUploads property but it doesn't work ....

Comment: Do you have a link to the actual plugin website/github? The jqueryscript.net site is terrible.

Comment: [https://github.com/cubiclesoft/jquery-fancyfileuploader](https://github.com/cubiclesoft/jquery-fancyfileuploader)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the option singleFileUpload listed on either link provided.  To stop multifile upload you can just remove the word multiple from your control.  For example on your page your upload control looks something like this

```
 <input id="demo" type="file" name="files" accept=".jpg, image/jpeg" multiple>
```

If you remove the word multiple at the end it should only allow your user to select one file at a time.